# Union between a Float and an array of unsigned char?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am parsing a stream of bytes that, once received, form an array of `uint8`.  It is known beforehand what the array contents are supposed to be, which can be either integers, a string, or a float.  All that is needed, is to reinterpret the data to those types.  Float is causing me some concerns though.

**My question**, is will the following structure work as expected without encountering any surprises?  (Memory aliasing, padding, endianness, etc.)  And if not, what would be the best way to achieve this with as little code as reasonable?

```
union BytesToFloat{
    float f;
    uint8 bytes[4];
}
```

As background, this data originates from save data, so it's possible for the computer writing the data, to not be the same as the computer reading it.

*edit*

After reading one of the comments concerning endianness, would this structure and helping function be a better fit, or will endian remain an issue (or could something else be troublesome beyond that)

```
union IntToFloat{
    float f;
    uint32 i;
};

uint32 CharToLong(unsigned char * c){
    uint32 val = c[0];
    val <<= 8;
    val |= c[1];
    val <<= 8;
    val |= c[2]; 
    val <<= 8;
    val |= c[3];
    return val;
}
```

Comment: The CPU/platform will affect the endianness. Therefore if your code may compile to different CPUs, you'd better use some bitwise operations to convert data yourself with a specific endianness.

Comment: Or perhaps cast from `float*` to `long*` like the [Fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)?

Comment: @AlvinWong: Surely that's not portable? On my platform, `long` is 64 bits wide.

Comment: @NPE What platform is it? (I thought for gcc x86 where `int`, `long` and `long int` are all 32-bit, where `long long` is 64-bit, but I could be wrong, but anyway you need to adapt to that compiler)

Comment: @AlvinWong: My platform is 64-bit x86. But that's not really the point. The point is that there's no relationship between `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(float)`. They just happen to be the same on  some platforms, but that's about it. Therefore reinterpreting one type as the other is inherently non-portable.

Comment: @AlvinWong - That looks promising!  I suppose in my case it'd be `i  = * ( uint32 * ) &f`

Comment: @Clairvoire: I really don't see how that's better than the `union`.

Comment: I didn't say that `long` must be 32-bit, but in my example it is. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @NPE - I don't either just yet.  I only said it looks promising since it was used in Doom's source, making it unlikely to have any subtle pitfalls (I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slightly improve the reliability of your `union` (more in theory than practice) by replacing the `4` with `sizeof(float)`.

However, you have to face other problems over a network.  There's no guarantee that both ends of the connection use IEEE 754 floating point format (for example, zSeries mainframes from IBM).  There's also no guarantee that both sides use the same byte order (Intel architecture uses little endian, most other architectures use big endian).  You need to know the byte orders of source and destination computers to interpret the data correctly (but the DRDA protocol used by IBM for communication with SQL DBMS works like that, with the 'receiver makes right' convention).

The endianness and byte order issues are practical issues; the floating point format tends to be less of an issue unless you're expecting to play with mainframe systems (they tend to be the holdouts on IEEE 754, primarily because their formats were settled before IEEE 754 was standardized).

Often, the best way to ship data is using a plain [text](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/textualitychapter.html) format.  It has advantages of easy debugging and avoiding many (but not all) the difficult issues of number representation.  However, if your primary protocol is binary, it would look odd to change it to text for floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be surprises.  At both ends.

How that code will work will be implementation defined at both reading and writing.

On the plus side, often the transport medium (network, or disk) is so slow that adding code to make the reading/writing deterministic will have no significant performance impact.

Another good thing is that code rarely has to run on arbitrary platforms.  Make sure that what you are doing works on each platform you support and you are good.